# Problems with creating a python function "getWordPoints" --Python

Tags: python, function, variables, global

Alright, so I need help, because i need to créate a function that calculates and returns the total point value (as an int) of myWord using the letterPoints dictionary which consists of letter:pointValue pairs. Its for a Scrabble Word Finder. I already created a dictionary with the letters. The function needs one parameter: "MyWords":

```
     global letterPoints
     letterPoints = {"A": 1, "B": 3, "C": 3, "D": 2, "E": 1, "F": 4, "G": 2, "H": 4, "I": 1, "J":8, "K": 5, "L": 1, "M": 3, "N": 1, "O": 1, "P": 3, "Q": 10, "R": 1, "S": 1, "T": 1, "U": 1, "V": 4, "W": 4, "X": 8, "Y": 4, "Z": 10}
```

Comment: Do you know how to access values from a dict? Do you know how to add values? What's the problem? If you don't know how to get started, take a look at [loops](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/237/loops/862/for-loops#t=201607260519137665561).

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) what did you try so far? This site doesn't work by calling for code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global letterPoints
letterPoints = {"A": 1, "B": 3, "C": 3, "D": 2, "E": 1, "F": 4, "G": 2, "H": 4, "I": 1, "J":8, "K": 5, "L": 1, "M": 3, "N": 1, "O": 1, "P": 3, "Q": 10, "R": 1, "S": 1, "T": 1, "U": 1, "V": 4, "W": 4, "X": 8, "Y": 4, "Z": 10}

def GetValues( MyWord ):
    total = 0
    for letter in MyWord:
        if letter  in letterPoints.keys():
            total = total + letterPoints[letter]
    return total
```

Comment: it keeps returning "0" the whole time.

Comment: Use capital letters or add this to the definition: MyWord = MyWord.upper()

Comment: First get rid of `global`. Second there is no need to call the `keys()` method. `if letter in letterPoints:` is enough. Third you should have a look at the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: It Works perfect! Thank You!